# How to grep a line of ps afux filtering by PID

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I just want to know how to grep a line which consists of for example 
pid with number 2.
I want to grep the whole line. Also, it is very important to filter only and exactly "2". Because at the moment It filters all the number which have 2 in it.

Comment: `ps` supports `-p 2` to show only the process with PID 2, would that help?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @kvantour - You are being recruited for the [Stack Overflow Close Vote Room (SOCVR)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Information on the room is located at [SOCVR FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq). The room focuses on questions that need extra attention like crap magnets. It is a place where folks work at greater efficiency than the queues. I think you would be a good fit.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the listing for just one particular PID, the `-p` option is the best way.

```
ps -f -p 2
```

for example

If you want `grep` to match a string only if it is the whole word, not part of another word, look at the `-w` flag, which matches words like

```
$ echo '52' | grep 2
52
$ echo '52' | grep -w 2
$
```

if you want to match against only a particular field, `awk` might be a better answer than `grep`.  For example, if we want to check if the second column is exactly 2 we could do

```
ps -af | awk '$2 == 2 {print}'
```

Comment: Hey man, I've been looking for exactly this answer ps -f -p 2. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for something like this. If you need the details of a process and you know the `pid` go for this.

```
ps afux | awk '{if($2==<pid>) print}'
```